# how to force button text to stick to the text specified in the layout

Tags: android, xml, button

I am using following layout xml. I specify the button's text as "Record", when it is displayed on the button it shows "RECORD"

how to make the button text appears as it specified in the xml layout.

**xml layout**

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_logFileAction"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="visible"
  android:text="Record"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default styling  for `Buttons`in Android includes `android:textAllCaps="true"` - so you could add this property to your Button, like:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/actConnect2_btn_logFileAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

If this is not working, you could try setting

```
yourButton.setTransformationMethod(null);
```